# Could 看不起 work as the Mandarin equivalent of 睇唔起?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese

This dictionary entry says the Mandarin equivalent of Cantonese's 睇唔起 is 瞧不起.

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15825/

Some Mandarin speakers seem to use 看不起.

Is 看不起 a valid way of expressing 睇唔起, or are those Mandarin speakers using the wrong term?

Comment: both 瞧不起. and 看不起 mean 睇唔起 in Cantonese

Comment: @TangHo great! could you post as an answer please so you can get credit? also is there a difference between 瞧不起. and 看不起?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is 看不起 a valid way of expressing 睇唔起*

It is a direct translation

瞧不起/ 看不起 in Mandarin = 睇唔起 in Cantonese

瞧得起/ 看得起 in Mandarin = 睇得起 in Cantonese

瞧不起 is more colloquial; 看不起 is more literary